# what is ew:CalendarPopup control in aspx

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, user-controls

I took a code from my friend. this code contains this element in the aspx page:

```
<ew:CalendarPopup
```

When I put the mouse on it, I got this message:

```
Element 'CalendarPopup' is not known element. This can occur if there is a compilation error in the web site, or the web config file is missing.
```

I have the web config file.

#### Edit

I found this in web.config file

```
<controls>
                <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
                <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="System.Web.UI.WebControls" assembly="System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
            </controls>
```

Comment: Ask your friend if he has developed any user control or added a third party control tool kit like telerik.

Comment: It seems like he is using some user control

Comment: if so you need to register user control

Comment: @DevrajGadhavi is it a famous component though not in .net ?

Comment: @shanish is it a famous component though not in .net ?

Comment: @MahmoudeElghandour is it a famous component though not in .net ?

Comment: @DevrajGadhavi is right you need to see if there is a custom control or third party add-on being used. You can find a little more out by looking for where the control is being registered http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2006/11/26/tip-trick-how-to-register-user-controls-and-custom-controls-in-web-config.aspx . Search the solution for tagPrefix="ew"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like he was using an [Excentrics World](http://www.eworldui.net/customcontrols/CalendarPopup.aspx) (hence the "ew:") Calendar Popup control.  There's a demo [here](http://www.eworldui.net/customcontrols/CalendarPopupDemo.aspx) that doesn't seem to work in chrome.

You should be able to download their entire control set [here](http://www.eworldui.net/Download.aspx).

Comment: I downloaded it and installed it. but how can I add it to my project?

Answer (score 1):

"EW" could be defined on the page in a `Register` tag like this:

```
<%@ Register TagPrefix="ew" Assembly="WhateverEwIs.Web" Namespace="WhateverEwIs.Web" %>
```

Or it could be defined in the Web.Config in the system.web > pages > controls section similar to this:

```
  <system.web>
    <pages>
      <controls>
        <add tagPrefix="ew" namespace="WhateverEwIs.Web" assembly="WhateverEwIs.Web" />
        <add tagPrefix="ew2" tagName="CalendarPopup" src="~/userControls/CalendarPopup.ascx" />
      </controls>
    </pages>
  </system.web>
```

Comment: If it's a third party control library (the Excentrics World controls were mentioned as a possibility in another answer) they'll need to be installed via standalone DLL files or with source code as classes or direct user controls.  There should be a ... tagPrefix="ew" ... somewhere on your page or in your web.config if the controls are installed.  Otherwise, you'll need to add them to your codebase.